# How to find the vector component of the following vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: Finding a vector]

I understand vectors, however this specific graph is a bit confusing to me. I'm thinking this vector represents [-1,-2], however not sure.

Could someone please explain this example?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is your definition of a vector?  What is the "vector component" of a "vector"?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the vector begins at $(1,-1)$ and ends at $(3,-3)$. To find vector components, simply subtract the coordinates of the beginning from the coordinates of the end: $(3-1,-3-(-1))$ or $(2,-2)$.